# How can I get a cookie/token from DefaultGraphQLWebSocketContext?

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, graphql-java

**Update**: I found this [example](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/samples/blob/master/subscription-with-authentication/src/main/java/subscription/MySubscriptionResolver.java) and it looks like the real question is how to get a cookie/token from

```
DefaultGraphQLWebSocketContext context = env.getContext();
```

I'm using [graphql-java-demo](https://github.com/npalm/graphql-java-demo) as a base project that uses spring boot (and [graphql-java-tools](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-tools/)) and I'm trying to setup auth using `request.cookie`.

I can inject `@Autowired HttpServletRequest request` into

```
@Component
public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    @Autowired
    private CloudService cloudService;

    private @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest request;

    public Optional<EnvMetadata> get_env_metadata() {
        System.out.println(request.getHeader("Cookie"));
        return cloudService.get_env_metadata();
    }
```

(it does output the cookie)

but when I try to do the same thing with [Subscription](https://github.com/npalm/graphql-java-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/ofouro/code/graphql/demo/resolvers/Subscription.java):

```
@Component
class Subscription implements GraphQLSubscriptionResolver {
```

there's the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

How can I inject `DispatcherServlet` or something to extract `request.cookie` from subscription request?

I guess I should *override* WebSocket connection properties somehow to save that `request.cookie`: [link](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-subscription-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/graphql/example/http/StockTickerWebSocket.java).

Answer (score 0):

Injecting seems to work for you, but you have to keep in mind, that it is technically impossible to get the request object injectes itself but a proxy which resolves the current request at runtime.
Your exception says that there is no request context when you try to get the request. Your method probably gets called outside of a request. E.g. a scheduled task or something similar?